# Vue.js doesn't re-render components with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to make a multiple text input component. There's a parent Vue component to manage individual fields and a component for a single input.

The parent component renders the child components via a v-for which is bound to an array of objects.

```
data() {
    return {
        lastItemId: 0,
        items: [{ id: this.lastItemId, value: '', showDeleteBtn: false}]
    }
},
```

Template:

```
<div>
    <input-item v-for='(item, index) in items'
                :key="item.id"
                :default-data="item"
                @itemAdded="addItemAfter(index)"></input-item>
</div>
```

Whenever the user starts typing in the last field in the list I'm emitting an event to add a new text field after it.

```
addItemAfter(index) {
    if (index == this.items.length - 1) {
        this.items.push({
            id: ++this.lastItemId,
            value: '',
            showDeleteBtn: false
        });
    }
}
```

This works just fine. However, I also need to update the item at the current index to display the delete button near that field. Whatever I do, Vue doesn't re-render that component, unless I set an object with a different ID to that index - which is not what I want.

**Things I have tried:**

```
this.items[index].showDeleteBtn = true;
```

---

```
let item = this.items[index];
item.showDeleteBtn = true;
this.$set(this.items, index, item);
```

---

```
let item = this.items[index];
item.showDeleteBtn = true;
this.items.splice(index, 1, item);
```

---

```
this.$set(this.items[index], 'showDeleteBtn', true);
```

---

**Update**

This is the most important in this problem part of the child component:

```
<button class="btn text-danger" v-show="showDeleteBtn" @click.prevent="removeItem">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
</button>

// ....................................

props: ['defaultData'],

data() {
    return {
        itemId: this.defaultData.id,
        item: this.defaultData.value,
        showDeleteBtn: this.defaultData.showDeleteBtn
    }
},
```

Comment: Well, the v-for doesn't have to re-render - the array didn't change. The `input-item` component(s) must re-render, and appearantly don't. So can you share their code/markup?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: The properties set in the `data` method are set once on initialization. They won't update in response to changes to the `defaultData` prop.

Comment: So how should I update that data? How else can I send data from the parent component down to a child component?

Comment: How about using computed() instead?

Comment: To clarify: the value of the `defaultData` prop will update in response to changes to the `item` value bound to the prop. But the `data` method won't get called again to update the `showDeleteBtn` data property. You could use a computed, or just specify a `showDeleteBtn` prop and pass that via `:show-delete-btn="item.showDeleteBtn"`

Comment: Thanks guys! Both methods are working, I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason the delete button is not showing up when you update the item is that the value of the `showDeleteBtn` property of your child component is not updating.

That value is not updating because the Vue instance properties set in the `data` method are only set once on initialization. So, `showDeleteBtn` is only ever set once in the `data` method:

```
showDeleteBtn: this.defaultData.showDeleteBtn
```

When you update the `showDeleteBtn` property of the `item` being bound as the `defaultData` prop, that changes the value of the `defaultData` object in the child component. However, that does not automatically update the `showDeleteBtn` property in the child component.

---

The simplest solution would be to make `showDeleteBtn` a computed property instead of a property set by the `data` method:

```
computed: {
  showDeleteBtn() {
    return this.defaultData.showDeleteBtn;
  }
}
```

This explicitly tells the Vue instance to update the `showDeleteBtn` value with the value of `this.defaultData.showDeleteBtn` if it ever changes.

---

Another solution would be to make `showDeleteBtn` a prop:

```
props: { defaultData: Object, showDeleteBtn: Boolean },
```

And bind the value of `item.showDeleteBtn` to that prop from the parent component:

```
<input-item 
  v-for='(item, index) in items'
  :key="item.id"
  :default-data="item"
  :show-delete-btn="item.showDeleteBtn"
  @itemAdded="addItemAfter(index)"
/>
```

This way, any changes to the value of `item.showDeleteBtn` will be directly reflected in the value of the `showDeleteBtn` prop of the child component.

This way also makes it a little clearer from the parent scope how changing that property on the `item` is going to affect the child component.